# sending axes as parameter in matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

I need a help with MatLab GUI .
I have a GUI with an axes on it, 
and a function `plotData(axes,data)` which has axes as parameter.
The GUI has a button "plot Data".

How can I do the following:
When the button is clicked, call the function `plotData` with the parameter `axes1` and the data that I want to plot? 
I want the plot to be directed to `axes1` which exists in the GUI.

It's suppose to be simple, but when I send the axes as parameter it doesn't plot on the GUI, or maybe it does but I cant see it.
It works fine for me without the function: just to plot the data. but to plot the data it's not 1 row :).

i tried calling ax which storing the GUI's axes handle on different M file, but since i call it as a function from different M file nothing happens with the GUI axes handle but it also not returning any error.

Comment: Can you show us some code?

Answer (score 1):

*Side remark:* Your question is a bit unclear: if you added **small** code snippet to illustrate what you have tried, better answers could be provided.

*To the question at hand:*

Have you tried directing the `plot` to `axis1` in `plotData`?

```
function [] = plotData( ax, data )
% make ax the current axes for plot
axes( ax ); 
% continue with plotting the data 
% ...
```

You can achieve the effect of `axes( ax );` in a more efficient way through the specific `plot` commands you are using.
For example, if you are using simple `plot`

```
plot( ax, data ); % plots data to axes ax
```

check the documentation of the specific `plot` command you are using for the axes argument.

Comment: hello Shai and thanks for your reply . the problem is the function is in external m-file and not the same one as where the gui m file is.

Comment: as long as you have `ax` storing the GUI's axes handle, it does not matter if `plotData` is in a different m file. Please try it out and post your results in your question, so other will be able to assist as well.